# Which classes aren't capped at level 20?

Tags: fire-emblem-fates

I've got my avatar at level 20, but they are capped at level 20 as a Bow Knight. It seems like *some* advanced classes aren't capped at level 20. For example, I have Jakob as a level 26 Great Knight, and Felicia as a level 23 Hero.

So that I can gain more skills for my avatar, which classes allow me to go above level 20?

Comment: Since Fates isn't yet released in Europe, I can't give an answer, but from my past experience with FE games, base classes that can't be promoted have a higher level cap than others to make up for it. I'm pretty sure the Great Knight and Hero are promoted classes, though, so they should have the same level cap as the Bow Knight.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are five classes that have a level cap of 40 instead of 20. These learn abilities at level 1, 10, 25, 35. Before level 20 they are considered a base class, after level 20 a promoted class. These means if you were to change from a 25 Dread Fighter to a Hero you would end up a level 5 Hero. **Or for your specific case changing from a level 20 Bow Knight to one of the below classes will make you level 40.** The only way to continue leveling your avatar is with an Eternal Seal, explained below.

**Dread Fighter** - Use a [Dread Scroll](http://fireemblem.wikia.com/wiki/Dread_Scroll) on any character. This can be acquired by having at least two paths downloaded to your 3DS. It will also become available with DLC maps at a future date.

**Dark Falcon** - Use an [Ebon Wing](http://fireemblem.wikia.com/wiki/Ebon_Wing) on any character. This can be aquired by having at all 3 paths downloaded to your 3DS. It will also become available with DLC maps at a future date.

**Lodestar** - Use a [Hero's Brand](http://fireemblem.wikia.com/wiki/Hero%27s_Brand) on a male character. This can be acquired once, by completing the "Before Awakening" DLC with Chrom, Lissa, and Fredrick still alive.

**Great Lord** - Use an [Exalt's Brand](http://fireemblem.wikia.com/wiki/Exalt%27s_Brand) on a female character. This can be acquired once. by completing the "Before Awakening" DLC with Chrom, Lissa, and Fredrick still alive.

**Singer** - This is Azura's staring class, and is unique to her.

However, any class can level past twenty using an [Eternal Seal](https://fireemblemwiki.org/wiki/Eternal_Seal). Which simply raises the level cap by 5. These can be purchased for a measly 12000 gold at a level 3 rod/staff shop.

Finally, Jakob and Felicia are special cases. They start the game as a promoted class (Maid/Butler) however their internal level is 1, not 21. This allows them and only them to break the leveling rules. They can level to 40 as any class.